# mercurial update hook gives me permission denied error

Tags: mercurial, permissions, dvcs, mercurial-hook

I am using SSH to push to the central mercurial repository on the remote server.

I put in a hook so the remote repo will update:

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg update >&2
```

when I try to push to the remote repo, the push succeeds, but I get this output:

```
remote: added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
remote: abort: Permission denied: /var/www/sites/businesslicenses/.hgignore
remote: warning: changegroup hook exited with status 255
```

any ideas for me?? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use SSH and don't setup a dedicated user account on your server, then you will need to ensure that:

- the necessary users are in a common group and
- newly created files belong to that group
- newly created files are group writable

See ["The filesystem method" in the wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MultipleCommitters) for more information. Generally, I find that it's easier to user a dedicated user on the server and then grant people access by adding SSH public keys to `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if /var/www/sites/businesslicenses/.hgignore is owned by the current user and is not owned by root.

Comment: it IS owned by root. but i need to have multiple users able to push to this central repository... so who should own it?